# In SVN, how do I copy just the subdirectories of a directory to another directory?

Tags: svn, copy

Via command line, I usually do this:

```
cp -rRp /path/to/a\_folder/. /path/to/another\_folder
```

This copies just the contents underneath **a_folder** to **another_folder**. In SVN I need to do the same thing, but can't figure it out. I always end up with this:

```
/path/to/another\_folder/a\_folder
```

SVN throws up even when I try this:

```
svn copy file:///path/to/a\_folder/* file:///path/to/another\_folder
```

It says it does not exist.

**EDIT:**

This would probably help. The directory structure for my project looks like this:

```
my_project
  /branches
  /tags
  /trunk
  /vendor
    /1.1
```

I need to get the contents of 1.1 under vendor into the trunk without it actually copying the 1.1 folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered using svn merge?

Given a repo like this:

```
trunk/a_folder/foo
trunk/a_folder/bar
trunk/new_folder/baz
```

use these commands to merge the foo and bar directories:

```
cd trunk/new_folder
svn merge -r1:HEAD http://svn/repo/trunk/a_folder .
```

Answer (score 22):

As you've certainly discovered, **copying to a target directory that already exists** won't work:

```
svn cp svn://my_project/vendor/1.1 svn://my_project/trunk
```

because trunk already exists, so you'd end up with:

```
svn://my_project/trunk/1.1
```

Using **merge** has the unfortunate property of not keeping history of the vendor 1.1 tag in subversion prior to 1.5 which introduced merge tracking. You may not care.  In this case merge would be the correct solution:

```
svn co svn://my_project/trunk trunk-wc
svn merge svn://my_project/trunk svn://my_project/vendor/1.1 trunk-wc
```

The best way to read this merge is: First determine the changes necessary to to make `trunk` identical to `vendor/1.1`, then apply those changes to the given working copy (also of trunk, in this case).

I should point out that this merge will effectively blow away anything that was in trunk previously. So, if you have local (non-vendor) modifications already on the trunk, you'll want to apply just the changes between 1.1 and the previous vendor drop:

```
svn co svn://my_project/trunk trunk-wc
svn merge svn://my_project/vendor/1.0 svn://my_prjoect/vendor/1.1 trunk-wc
```

If **trunk exists, but is empty** you've got two choices: replace the trunk, or write a little shell loop:

**Replacing the trunk** looks like this:

```
svn rm svn://my_project/trunk
svn cp svn://my_project/vendor/1.1 svn://my_project/trunk
```

**Leveraging the shell** (bash):

```
svn co svn://my_project/trunk trunk
svn co svn://my_project/vendor/1.1 1.1
( cd 1.1
  for x in * ; do
    svn cp $x ../trunk
  done 
)
svn ci trunk
```

Answer (score 6):

This link explains a workaround.

http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2004-12/1537.shtml

Basically what it says is that if the destination folder is not existing in the repo, you will get the contencts of your source folder in the destination folder.

See below example. The folder 07-03-2012 does not exist in your repo. Once you execute the below command, you will get the contents of HEAD folder in 07-03-2012.

```
svn cp <URL>/HEAD/ <URL>/branches/07-03-2012 -m "test"
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that what you want is that the contents of the trunk end up in the `/tags/version-1.0/` folder without there being an extra `/trunk` folder there.  i.e.  This is bad:  `/tags/version-1.0/trunk/stuff`.  This is good: `/tags/version-1.0/stuff`.

To get this I do a 2 step process:

```
svn copy http://localhost/MyProject/trunk    http://localhost/MyProject/tags/

# now I have /MyProject/tags/trunk

svn rename http://localhost/MyProject/tags/trunk  http://localhost/MyProject/tags/version-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very, very close:

```
svn copy -m"Copy Directory" file:///path/to/a_folder file:///path/to/another_folder
```

just drop the `/*` from the first argument.

Comment: This is not helpful, as op wants to copy subdirectories to the other folder, and not the folder itself to the other folder.