# SVN: how to merge tags from separate projects

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have a single SVN repository with two separate projects:

```
project_1
    /trunk
    /branches
        /1.0
    /tags
        /1.0.0

project_2
    /trunk
    /branches
        /1.0
    /tags
        /1.0.0
```

As you can see, each has identical branch/tag numbers.  Imagine there are different files in each project.

I want to merge these into a single new project, `project_3`.  That is, the `trunk` of the new project will have all files/histories from the `trunk` of `project_1` and `project_2`, the `1.0` branch will have all files/histories from the `1.0` branches of `project_1` and `project_2`, and the `1.0.0` tag will have all files/histories from the `1.0.0` tags of `project_1` and `project_2`.

My first thought was to do accomplish this using multiple `svn cp` executions. A big problem I ran into was [not being able to copy just the subdirectories of a directory to another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260658/in-svn-how-do-i-copy-just-the-subdirectories-of-a-directory-to-another-director). I am having trouble understanding whether the solutions discussed in that post apply to the situation here.  Also, the post and many of the solutions are six years old and I wonder whether there have been any change to SVN that would help here.

The goal is to have a single unified project with as much history preserved as possible.  What is the best approach to take here?  Please note that switching to another VCS is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to merge data **and** history, you can't use SVN copy" you must to use dump|load cycles:

`svnrdump sump URL/OF/DIR ... > dump` + `svnadmin load --ignore-uuid --parent-dir NEW_PARENT ... < dump`

Instead of svnrdump you can try `svnadmin dump | svndumpfilter`

Comment: Is there a way to make `svnadmin load` work with a repository URL or can it only work with something locally checked out?

Comment: @sparc_spread no, you are loading the dump not the actual repo. You could try fudging things with svnsync but that's a very advanced job. I would dump both repos and import them both into a new repo.

Comment: Right now there is just one repo with two projects, and I'm hoping to just make a third project in the same repo.  Is this doable or do you think I need a new repo?

Comment: @sparc_spread - doable, but new special repo will be better choice

Comment: Looks like I can also use `svnrdump load` to work with a remote repository as the destination.  The only thing I can't do is have `project_1/branches/1.0` and `project_2/branches/1.0` end up in the new `project_3/branches/1.0`.  They end up in whatever parent dir I specify, each with the path `project_.../1.0` under that.  Then I have to actually checkout the new files to a working tree and move them with `svn mv`, which unlike other options will accept a wildcard.  If this is the only approach, no prob.  If you can suggest a better one, please do so here. Either way, I'm marking as answered.

Comment: @sparc_spread - you can't `svnrdump load`, because if this case you'll get the same path, as it was in original repo with `project_*` prefix. Only svndump will allow you to change "mount-point" of dumped repository. If you can you svndump with new (remote?) repo, you can load dumps in local repository, test results, make full dump again in send it to repo-admin

Comment: I'm sorry, when you say "Only `svndump` will allow..." do you mean `svnadmin load` with the `--parent-dir` option?

Comment: I tried:  `svnrdump dump https://OLD/REPO/URL/project_1/trunk > d1` and then `svnadmin load NEW/REPO/LOCAL/PATH --parent-dir project_3/trunk --ignore-uuid < d1`. When I do an `svn ls file:///NEW/REPO/LOCAL/PATH/project_3/trunk`. I find the contents to be `project_1` instead of the files from `project_1/trunk` - the same issue I get from using `svnrdump load`.  Which portion of this should I change?

Comment: 1. Yes, I thought "...`svnadin load`" 2. If you want to merge trunks with different prefixes you must use `--parent-dir` at one level higher, than joinable dirs: `--parent-dir project_3` for **both trunks** (TBT!!! After load you *may* get `project_1/trunk` inside `project_3`)

Comment: Yeah, looks like the result of that is `project_3/project_1/trunk`. No problem, I can correct by checking out the new tree and doing an `svn mv project_3/project_1/trunk/* project_3/trunk`. I don't mind "polluting" the history with an extra `mv`, and I am going to script it so not a lot of drudgery. Please let me know whether or not there are any last alternatives I should try. Again if not, no problem.

Comment: @sparc_spread - it seems you *must* to use svndumpfilter before loading dump. Just as sample - https://blog.vbfox.net/post/2012/02/11/Using-svndumpfilter-to-extract-a-folder-in-it-s-own-repository is almost your use-case

Comment: Thanks for finding this and for all your help!